# Where does all data send with nodejs method socket.write?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

Good day! Where does all data send when nodejs method `socket.write` is called? I understand that socket runs of the server side for each client. But where exactly does data go? to client? On official nodejs documentanion there is no info about destination. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot successfully `write` to a socket unless you (or some part of your nodejs software) first `connect`s it to some other socket somewhere.

A [socket server `listen`s for connection requests](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen), and then [`accept`s](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_connection) them as they arrive.  (When you use node express to make a web server, express handles this for you.)  A client [`connect`s](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection) to a socket server. Once the pair of sockets are connected, data you `write` into one of the sockets causes a [`data` event](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_data) on the other one.

The two sockets may be on different machines in different locations. That's the miracle of global networking.

So where does data you `write` go?  To the other socket in the pair.

If you are using datagrams (not connections) it's slightly different. The data you `write` contains the destination address. But you probably are not using  databgrams. If you are, you are probably using a protocol stack like RTSP or UDP instead of TCP.